# Utilizar Datepart como parâmetro de Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e estou esbarrando em uma consulta SQL que consiste em o usuário pesquisar por Data e terá a opção de escolher se a consulta será feita adicionando Final de Semana a essas datas, excluindo o final de semana ou só consultando o Final de Semana.

No caso, tenho uma View que será usada para esta aplicação. O problema é que ela não tem um campo específico para o dia da semana, então tive que fazer um DatePart.

O problema é que quando eu utilizo com outros elementos da consulta, da erro nela.

Já tentei dentro da Query, com Join, com Union, com Having, criando um Banco auxiliar para comparar e nada. Alguém poderia me explicar de como isso poderia ser feito?

Segue abaixo o código das duas tabelas.

```
SELECT [DT_ABERT_OPER], DATEPART(weekday, [DT_ABERT_OPER]) AS 
DIA_DA_SEMANA
FROM [dbo].[reavw001_ocorrencias_xxxxx] WHERE [DT_ABERT_OPER] 
BETWEEN '2017-11-03' AND '2017-11-05'
```

No Caso, fiz essa consulta teste para retornar o DatePart dos dias 03 ao 05. Retornou 6 para as ocorrências do dia 03(Sexta), 7 para as do dia 4(Sábado) e 1 para o Domingo, o problema é que a consulta final será uma média destas ocorrências e o total de horas que ela ficou fora. E nisso, o dia da semana não está se encaixando.

Segue abaixo a consulta final que preciso encaixar a escolha de Final de Semana.

```
SELECT GITEC,   SUM (DATEDIFF (minute,INICIO,DH_ULTIMA_CATEGORIZACAO)) 
as Soma_tempo, 
AVG (DATEDIFF (minute,INICIO,DH_ULTIMA_CATEGORIZACAO)) as Media_tempo 
FROM [readb004].[dbo].[reavw001_ocorrencias_xxxxxx] WHERE 
([DT_ABERT_OPER]
BETWEEN '2017-11-03' AND '2017-11-06 23:59:59') GROUP BY GITEC order 
by GITEC DESC
```

O que poderá ser feito para solucionara isso? Uma procedure ou tem algum outro jeito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você quer buscar utilizando os dias da semana, pode tratar o `DATEPART` como um inteiro.

No caso da busca para dias da semana:

```
SELECT *
  FROM view v
 WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, v.data) NOT IN (7, 1) -- Qualquer dia que não seja Sábado ou Domingo
```

Caso queira apenas os fins de semana:

```
SELECT *
  FROM view v
 WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, v.data) IN (7, 1) -- Qualquer dia que seja Sábado ou Domingo
```

Se quiser trabalhar com variáveis:

```
DECLARE @opcao INT;

SET @opcao = 1; -- Use 1 para dias da semana, 2 para fins de semana e 3 para todos os dias

SELECT *
FROM view v
WHERE @opcao = 3
  OR (@opcao = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, v.data) NOT IN (7, 1))
  OR (@opcao = 2 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, v.data) IN (7, 1))
```

Caso queira adicionar o intervalo de data na consulta acima:

```
DECLARE @opcao INT;

SET @opcao = 1; -- Use 1 para dias da semana, 2 para fins de semana e 3 para todos os dias

SELECT *
FROM view v
WHERE v.data BETWEEN '2017-11-03' AND '2017-11-06 23:59:59'
 AND (@opcao = 3
  OR (@opcao = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, v.data) NOT IN (7, 1))
  OR (@opcao = 2 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, v.data) IN (7, 1)))
```

Comment: O valor retornado por DATEPART(weekday, ...) não é constante para um mesmo dia da semana, pois varia de acordo com a configuração de DATEFIRST. Aliás, isto consta na documentação: "When datepart is week (wk, ww) or weekday (dw), the return value depends on the value that is set by using SET DATEFIRST".

Comment: @JoséDiz sim, e se você ler a pergunta vai ver qual a configuração para caso dele. Mais uma vez, acho que falta a leitura do `downvote` para você, mas se quiser continuar prejudicando todas as respostas que dou, inclusive as de linguagens que você não tem domínio e nem competência para avaliar vou procurar a moderação.

Comment: Deu certo. funcionou perfeitamente